# Convert Humax recordings to mp4

Tags: video, conversion, humax

I have some recordings on my Humax HDR Fox T2 that i'd like to convert to mp4 video so I can put them on the ipad.  For each recording, i have four files, eg:

```
  13K  Hey Duggee_20160217_0741.hmt
 330K  Hey Duggee_20160217_0741.nts
  43K  Hey Duggee_20160217_0741.thm
 127M  Hey Duggee_20160217_0741.ts
```

Judging by the file size, it looks like the .ts file is the video data, I don't know what the other files are for.  I've tried loading the .ts file into Handbrake and VLC and they don't seem to recognise it.  I've also tried converting it with ffmpeg, and get this error message back:

```
Hey Duggee_20160217_0741.ts: could not find codec parameters
```

Do I need to read something from the other files? Is there some encryption perhaps?  Grateful for any advice.  I'm using Linux btw.

Max

Comment: This is not a Question and Answer forum, What has your research effort shown using Google? Questions on SU are expected to show some research effort on your part and should be included in your question.

Comment: @Moab it *is* a question and answer forum isn't it?  But, i take you point about showing research.  I did google it and try a lot of things but the only thing really worth repeating was "Use ffmpeg" and i posted the results of that in my question.  As i stated i tried to open it in VLC and also tried to convert with ffmpeg - don't they count as "some research effort on my part"?  There are plenty of questions on SU and other stackexchange sites that list "I have tried a, b, and c" but don't show google search histories.

Comment: No its not a forum, let me reword it....Questions on SU are expected to [show some research effort](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) on your part and should be included in your question please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done if you make your recordings in standard format, not HD.
Then you can copy the recordings to a USB stick, the '.TS' files can then
be edited by 'VideoRedo' to remove commercials etc.
When done, there are options to save the video to various formats.

Answer (score 1):

[This wiki](http://wiki.hummy.tv/wiki/Main_Page) is a place where you should look into. From [FTP Hi-Def Content Using FOXY](http://wiki.hummy.tv/wiki/FTP_Hi-Def_Content_Using_FOXY):

> On the HDR both Hi-Def. and Standard-Def (SD). files are encrypted on the internal Hard Disk drive...

So yes, this file is encrypted. FYI .ts file stands for [MPEG transport stream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG_transport_stream) and as you assumed it contains encoded (and in your case also encrypted) video data. I can not tell you how to decrypt this file but maybe you will find some ideas in the link above ;)

Comment: At first glance, it looks like it's not possible, using the standard firmware (which i have) to remove the files in such a way that you're able to decrypt them:  the decryption happens at play time via the private key on the box.

Comment: I'm marking this as correct since it led me to discover that it doesn't seem to be possible to do what i want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe record them to a DVD recorder instead and then convert the DVD recording?

I know this is a bit more long winded but it may be the easiest way to do this.

Regards,

John O.

Comment: Long winded? You gave one sentence that is a suggestion. Also, what benefit is to be derived from encoding for DVD and then Ripping from DVD? It's perfectly possible to convert form one digital format to another without having to write to DVD in the interim.